Mexican hat normalization
The mexican hat or Ricker wavelet has the form (according to Wikipedia):
$$
\psi(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sigma}\pi^{1/4}} \left(1 - \left(\frac{t}{\sigma}\right)^2 \right) e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
or in 2D:
$$
\psi(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi\sigma^4}\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\right) e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
These are referred to as "normalized" functions. But how exactly are they are normalized? In other words, they are normalized to what?
When I calculate the energy integral ($L^2$-norm) I obtain $1$ for the 1D case but $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma^3$ for the 2D case.

Probably, you have a mistake in your calculations.


Thanks for pointing that out, there was indeed a mistake in my calculation of the 1D case (I edited the question to correct this). But the second one still doesn't normalize to 1 - I verified with Wolfram Alpha (via integration in polar coordinates).

In the L2 norm, it is really not normalized. But there in Wikipedia it is written under the formula that the multiplier for the multidimensional case must be understood in the L1 norm

OK, well that makes sense then, thanks! I wish I could find more information about why (or in which cases) L1 or L2 norms would be preferred.

L1 norm is best to visualize directly the amplitude of a narrowband oscillation from the modulus of the CWT, whereas the square of the CWT with L2 norm for noisy signals has the same PSD trend. Also see my answer here.
